# Comment actions missing at Review pages

Tags: bug, comments, review

At the [Close Votes](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close) and [Reopen Votes](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen) Review pages<sup>1)</sup>, when you hover the area next to a comment, the buttons for upvoting and flagging a comment do not light up.<sup>2)</sup>

After clicking the *"add / show n more comments"* button, the buttons re-appear:

[image]

Unfortunatily that option is not available when there are just a few comments.

<sub>1) This glitch is not seen on the [First Posts](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts) and [Low Quality Posts](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts) Review pages.</sub>

<sup>2) Observed in Chrome 31, IE 11, Firefox 25, Opera 12.</sup>